# How to convert the following tableau calculation into DAX powerbi?

Tags: powerbi, dax, tableau-desktop

I have a tableau measure which goes like this:

```
ColumnA= IF [Rating Projection Year 1] = 2021
THEN SUM([Weights Ly]*[Next year rating predicted (1)]*[Inclusion Flag Ly])/SUM([Weights Ly]*[Inclusion Flag Ly])
ELSEIF  [Rating Projection Year 1] = 2022
THEN SUM([Weights Cy]*[Next year rating predicted (1)]*[Inclusion Flag Cy])/SUM([Weights Cy]*[Inclusion Flag Cy])
ELSE 0
END
```

How can I convert the same in DAX powerbi? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this(Switch Case):

```
ColumnA = SWITCH(TRUE(), 
[Rating Projection Year 1] = 2021, SUM([Weights Ly] * [Next year rating predicted (1)]*[Inclusion Flag Ly])/SUM([Weights Ly] * [Inclusion Flag Ly]),
[Rating Projection Year 1] = 2022, SUM([Weights Cy] * [Next year rating predicted (1)]*[Inclusion Flag Cy])/SUM([Weights Cy] * [Inclusion Flag Cy]),
0)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).